# Windows Form application run on Windows hosting service

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, web-deployment

I've created a Windows Forms application that basically contains an HttpListener which launch a Form for each request. I have to show forms server side because I have to take a snapshot of what it's shown on the screen to send it to the client.
I've also made a asp.net web application in which I show those images sent from the HttpListener who act as a server.
Everything works fine on my machine but now that I must deploy it on my company's website I dont know how to do it, anyone has a solution? I haven't remote control on server, I can just upload files inside using FTP. 
What if I create a page inside my web application to launch the exe file? Any suggestion is really welcome!

Comment: It really sounds like you need to rethink your architecture - what you're describing sounds like a nightmare.  What is it that you are rendering on a form that needs to be snapshot?

Comment: Something that use OpenGL, so I can take snapshot once it appears on the screen. So one clear thinig is that I must show winForm, and it's not the only cause I have also to capture commands from web request to do something to refresh the screen, that's why I used an HttpListener! It's a nightmare anyway :)
If you have any idea to redesign this please share it with me!

Comment: Why do you need to take a snapshot to begin with?  No hosted provider with a brain will allow you to launch EXE files on their web server, so just what are you doing that cannot be done on the client side?

Comment: I know it's gonna difficult to have the right permission to operate but with all these requirements I didnt find another solution, as i said Im really open to any suggestion to improve or redesign my application.

Answer (score 0):

I'm definitely no OpenGL expert but I believe that its possible to use OpenGL to render a scene without displaying it to a screen.  Some preliminary research indicates that "pbuffers" allow you to render an image to a texture (which would presumably then allow for programatic access).

[Can i save an OpenGL scene as an image without showing it?](http://compgroups.net/comp.graphics.api.opengl/Can-i-save-an-OpenGL-scene-as-an-image-without-showing-it)

Note that using OpenGL probably depends on the server machine having a suitable graphics card.  As most servers don't come with very capable graphics card (some servers don't come with *any* graphics card) this is definitely something that you should check beforehand.